# Что означает имя Буратино?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, литература

Толстой полностью изменил сюжет сказки К. Коллоди и поменял имена персонажей. Но некоторые имена там вполне себе понятные (кот Базилио, лиса Алиса, папа Карло и т.д.).

Что, например, означает имя Буратино? Это итальянское слово или нет?
И еще интересно: Карабас-Барабас и Дуремар — просто игра слов или тоже реальные имена?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Burattino - деревянная/ тряпичная/ из папье-маше кукла; "одевается" на руку и "оживает" :-)Синоним: марионетка. В общем, наш Петрушка тоже burattino. Что касается других персонажей, то мне приходит в голову только ассоциация Барабас - barba (борода). Все остальное, скорее всего, фантазия писателя. Хотя, вот нашла, dur по франц. означает "жесткий, щетинистый".

Comment: Всплыл вопрос. Не ответил я тогда... Не знаю, что там по-итальянски, но по-русски тряпичная кукла, надиваемая на руку, - это никак не марионетка. Марионетка - это определенный тип куклы, всего из три.  Кроме наладонных есть управляемые снизу (на палках)  и сверху (на веревочках). Вот последний, "веревочный", и есть марионетка, хотя название иногда переносят и на "палочный". Но никак не на наладонный.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: А что  до информации в итальянской википедии, то я не вижу там даже упоминания о связи Пиноккио и куклы "бураттино". В любом случае получается, что имя изобретено Толстым, пусть даже и по итальянским "лекалам".

Comment: @behemothus  В итальянской [книжке](http://www.pinocchio.it/Download/Testo_ufficiale_LeAvventure_di_Pinocchio.pdf) Пиноккио постоянно называют burattino, так же как у нас Матроскина - котом. Толстой просто сделал нарицательное имя собственным.

Comment: @jmster это вервия тут упоминалась. Но пока я, не зная итальянского, не могу подтвердить, что "бураттини" в оригинале используется как обозначение Пиноккио. Да, там  встречается... Но по гуглопереводу совсем не так очевидно. Вообще вопрос уже настолько давний, мне не просто будет вернуться по склерозу, да и времени жалко. Но попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Имя "Буратино" выдумано Толстым, никаких следов в итальянском у него нет. Некоторые версии критики не выдерживают. 
http://fedro17.livejournal.com/86587.html

Аналогично и Барабас (При этом Карабас - реальная фамилия, правда французская) и Дуремар.

Бураттино (burattino) - это действительно кукла, марионетка, второстепенный персонаж комедии масок. Но она никак не связана с образом пиноккио.

Comment: Burattino - это общее название, не имя личное.

Comment: Так Pinocchio как раз burattino и есть. По ассоциации, можно назвать собаку Догом, читай, Собакой.

Comment: >Burattino - это общее название, не имя личное.  
  
Не совсем так. См. Вики. Изначально это вполне себе личное имя. См. Вики. Потом так стали называть определенный ***тип*** куклы.  Никак не "вообще".
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE  
 
Сейчас ситуция еще раз изменилась.

>Так Pinocchio как раз burattino и есть. По ассоциации, можно назвать собаку Догом, читай, Собакой.   
  
Вот тут вообще не понял.

Comment: >Vide la sua parrucca gialla in mano del **burattino**.  
— Pinocchio!... rendimi subito la mia parrucca!

Из оригинального текста сказки http://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_avventure_di_Pinocchio/Capitolo_3

Пиноккио в сказке Коллоди был "бураттиной", об этом же написано и в итальянской версии Википедии http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burattino#cite_note-1

Comment: Все верно, Марк Из, Collodi называл своего Pinocchio не марионеткой, каковым он на самом деле является, а burattino "..поскольку в конце 18 века этот термин обрел такую популярность, что его стали употреблять как общее название театральных кукол." Из ит. версии Вики.

Comment: <Не совсем так. См. Вики. Изначально это вполне себе личное имя. См. Вики. Потом так стали называть определенный тип куклы. Никак не "вообще".> 
Честно говоря, в этом случае я склонна больше доверять итальянской версии Вики (все-таки, она компетентней в конкретной тема вопроса), которая дословно говорит, что "термин burattino входит в обиход в 16 веке (т.е. гораздо раньше выхода в свет Lе avventure di Pinocchio в 1881 г.). =>

Comment: Я продолжил дискуссию под ответом natasha.  Здесь продублирую тезис. ***Буратино не марионетка, это другой тип куклы***.

Comment: Барабас (Barabbas) тоже реальная фамилия, правда, исковерканная. Так в латинской библии зовут разбойника, которого Пилат помиловал, Иешуа бар-Абба или Варавва. Но Толстому, конечно, просто понравилась рифма с Карабасом.

Comment: Не думаю, что у Барабаса реально библейскик корни... Больно уж странно выводить из библии, когда есть реальная французская фамилия Карабас. Но это здесь вопрос побочный.

Answer (score 0):

Итальянский, натурально, лексически укореняется в латыни, так что этимологию следует искать среди латинских лексических основ.
Во-первых, аффикс **-ino** указывает на форму деминутива, сиречь "маленький". Во-вторых, основа **bur-** **(-tt-** , натурально, отбрасываем как гляйдовое[*sic!*] образование); ищем в латыни это самое *bur-.* Прямого соответствия нет, и слава богу, а то бы возникли подозрения...
Но вот что есть: *burrae* — "глупости", явно *pluralis*,  так что имеем *burra*-.
Далее: сонорный эквивалент *bulla-*, вообще говоря, — "пузырь, шарик", однако, имеет фразеологическую коннотацию — "детский, ребячливый".
*Quod erat demonstrandum*, как прежде говаривали схоласты, исходная лексическая основа для **bura-tt-ino** — "глупость, ребячливость".